# Installing opentaps after downloading from AWS

Tags: crm, erp, opentaps

I have downloaded Opentaps 1.5 on my PC. There are many folders in the zip. How do I go about installing and launching the software.

Answer (score 1):

1) unzip it
2) cd into the unzipped dir
3) make sure you have a compatible java version -> java -version == 1.6
4) `./ant run-install`   --> load all the demo data
5) `./ant run`  --> run the system 
6) go to http://localhost:8080/opentaps/control/main  to access the app

default user: admin
default pass: opentaps